# How to assign an item in a table definition to another item within the same table?

Tags: lua, lua-table

I tried to assign an item within a curly-bracket definition of a table to another item which was defined previously. But Lua says it cannot find the table itself once referring to it within its definition.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to achieve:

```
local t = {
    a = 1,
    b = 2,
    c = t.a + t.b
}
```

Once approaching `t.a`, Lua will fail to find `t` and reply with an error.

How can I reference `t.a` and `t.b` while defining `c` within `t` **without leaving the curly bracket definition**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Awkward, but:

```
local t
do
    local a = 1
    local b = 2

    t = {a, b, c = a + b}           
end

print(t.c) -- 3
```

Without the `do/end` block, the `a` and `b` variables would be visible outside of `t`.

To my knowledge, there’s no direct way to refer to `a` and `b`, unless either 1) those variables exist beforehand (above example) or 2) once the table construction is complete.

Answer (score 3):

As put in your question, you can't.

"[The order of the assignments in a constructor is undefined](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.4.9)."

So, "defined previously" is not a concept within a table constructor.

Also, "[The assignment statement first evaluates all its expressions and only then the assignments are performed](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.3.3)."

And, "[The scope of a local variable begins at the first statement after its declaration](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#3.5)".

So, the local variable `t` shown in your code before the end of the statement cannot be referenced. `t` would be bound to a previously declared variable or global named `t`.